# Topic Modeling tool multilingual

Tags: multilingual, lda, topic-modeling

In the past few days I have been trying to work with the tool understanding topic modeling for multiple languages. This is the tool I have been trying to understand.

https://code.google.com/p/topic-modeling-tool/

Well my first question is to know whether it works for other languages like Hindi, Spanish,French and many others.

If it works with other languages then Can anyone explain the input procedure for languages like Hindi, Spanish, etc. ? I know that it works for English really well. Please help me out. Thanking everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the discussion [here](https://code.google.com/p/topic-modeling-tool/issues/detail?id=3), people have been using it for French and Russian

Comment: Is there any other tool which can help me understand multilingual topic modeling ?

Comment: If you want to "understand" multilingual topic modelling, you need to read papers, http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=multilingual+topic+modeling

Comment: Yeah I will start to read all the papers but i want to see a working example of it. It allows me to work on it if I have an idea of how the tool works. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Happy to help. Remember to upvote answer so that it helps others as well

Comment: Yeah but I dont have enough reputation to upvote the moment I get enough reputation I will upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You may like this other open-source project: 
https://github.com/ArtificiAI/Multilingual-Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation-LDA

Here is a tutorial on how to use it for many languages and with explanations on what it does: 
https://github.com/ArtificiAI/Multilingual-Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation-LDA/blob/master/Multilingual-LDA-Pipeline-Tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Hello, how do you install it in Jupiter Notebook? I tried to pip install but it can't seem to find it. Thanks!